# Custom tooltip doesn't work on fontawesome icon

Tags: html, css

I have a close button symbol which shows a top tooltip on hover pointing downwards. I have taken this example from https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_arrow_bottom

```
<div id="middle">
   <div class="posts">
    <a href="#close"><i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"><span class="tooltiptext">Exit</span></i></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.posts {
    background:white;
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-radius:4px;
    padding:20px;
    position:relative;
}
.posts a i.tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
.posts a i.tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
.posts a:hover i.tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Tooltip is not showing.

Comment: Your CSS selectors aren't being applied.  Using a space between selectors for classes, ids or elements are in descending order.  So, ".posts a .tooltiptext" applies nothing.  It should be ".posts a i .tooltiptext", the same is true for your tooltiptext::after selector.  It should be ".posts a i .tooltiptext::after", etc.  Also, since the boundries aren't set for the parent(s), using "position: absolute" with ".posts a i .tooltiptext" places it off screen.

Comment: After applying the above changes, now I'm getting Exit written next to the button instead of showing as a tooltip onhover. What's the problem. I have updated the code with new CSS code.@NathanChampion

Answer (score 0):

Please add style to **posts** class

```
.posts{
  position:relative;
  margin:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```css
.posts{
  position:relative;
  margin:60px;
  text-align:center;
}
.posts a .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
.posts a .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
.posts a:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<div id="middle">
   <div class="posts">
    <a href="#close"><i class="fas fa-times fa-lg"><span class="tooltiptext">Exit</span></i></a>
   </div>
</div>
```